# Debugging ExtJS 4 using console.log()

Tags: javascript, extjs, firebug, aptana

I am very new to ExtJS and still going through the Docs in Sencha site. I've seen a lot of [**examples**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/data) in ExtJS4 using console.log() for debugging. However I couldn't figure out how to deal with console.log().

I am using Aptana Studio 3 for development, and I don't think Aptana can run console.log() (correct me if im wrong). So we need to debug it in Firebug? Then how to incorporate script files like ext-all.js, ext-debug.js into Firebug?

Comment: Be careful when using these as they will break IE if they are left in. If you are planning on deploying an application using ExtJS wrap all your console.log outputs like so //<debug> console.log('test');
//</debug>

This way when you minify your app using Sencha SDK Tools you won't have to strip all the console.log entries manually to make IE work

Comment: Or include code like the following in your main app.js file:
`if (typeof console === "undefined") {  
    console = {  
        log: function () { },  
        info: function () { },  
        warn: function () { },  
        error: function () { }  
    };  
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, the `console.log()` output from your scripts goes to the console window of the developer tools of whatever browser you're using (e.g. Firebug for Firefox).  The browser developer tool picks up the script files from the same place the browser does; i.e. however you have them loaded into your web page.

Comment: Thanks, so I actually have to create a HTML markup to wrap the scripts up, and render the HTML in a browser (say Firefox), then I can view the console output in Firebug?

Comment: No, I meant the web pages that load those scripts for your app make them available to Firebug as well.  You don't need to do anything specifically for Firebug.

Comment: Yes, the scripts will be loaded when rendering the page. Suppose I have a standalone `.js` file: `var a = "my string"; console.log(a); `How can I see the output in Firebug or whatever places. (Note: I am not typing this in Firebug console, I just want to run the js file and see the output in the console). If having time please take a look at this [link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/data), how they output the `console.log()` content. Thanks

Comment: You'd have to create a simple HTML file that loads that script and then open the HTML file in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks this works fine! I came across another issue with ExtJS, would you mind taking a look at that if you got some thought.?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Google chrome. It has a very good developer tool.
Apart from that for ExtJs, use ext-all-dev.js file instead of ext-all.js or ext-all-debug.js while doing any development. It will be really helpful.
Check [this link](http://atechiediary.blogspot.com/2013/06/extjs-ext-all-debugjs-vs-ext-all-devjs_18.html) for more details.

Also you can set breakpoints by simply using the command `debugger;` in your javascript file.
But to make this work make sure firebug/developer tool is running.

Hope this helps.